# Should I build a separate dimension for Visas?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling, fact

I am designing a data mart for University students and confused about visa and passport information that should it go in the student dimension or should I define a separate dimension for it. Which would be the better approach?

Comment: student applying for the university is a business process and the grain is to capture all the details related to the student/applicant.

Comment: Thanks Marek, This information could be useful to slice and dice the students data according to their nationality and the type of visas they hold. It is possible for a student to have multiple visas during their course of study but passport probably would be the same.

Comment: But can a student have more than one visa at a time? If not, add this information to the Student dimension and make it an SCD2 one.